# Google Maps Timetable app

Tags: android, json, icalendar

Basically I'm trying to make an app that takes a students timetable and converts it into a map of my college campus with symbols illustrating where to be at a perticular time, all illustrated on google maps. There should be a gps tracker to your phone aswell as a symbol on what building your next class is in.

The problem is I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the idea of getting information for each student, as their are about 20000 students in my university. You can get a better understanding by following this link 
http://tt.daniel.ie/ and using my ID number 11108215. Basically I want to temporarilly store the time of each class and the building in which it will take place before drawing the position of the building to my map. All uniquely done for each student

Now Ive been following the new Boston Tuts which have been really helpfull so far but he's beginning to use JSON to get information like 'last tweets' from twitter. I dont know if this will be usefull in the long run and if JSON even applies to what im looking for. Also he uses a url 
"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mybringback" with mybringback(at the end) referring to his username(although this could work for any username). What would be the URL for the website I gave above (timetable) or can it even be used in this context. Another possible way forward is to download an ICal file from the timetable website (It gives the option below where you enter ID number) but I really wouldnt know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is the `location` property of icalendar files in conjunction with the `geo` property.

your icalendar files are probably only populated with `location` but once you have the GPS coordinate of each class room you could have the icalendar enahnced with the GPS coordinate stored in the `geo` property.

once you have the `geo` property, the GPS could give direction from A to B.